# Transaction Inserts in Liferay Service Builder

Tags: liferay, liferay-service-builder

I have to perform multiple inserts using for-loop in DB using service builder, is there any way to insert into the DB using transactions so that all the inserts are performed together without hitting the Database for every inserts.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess it is not possible. 
See the comment from David H Nebinger in the below link https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/54666240
Liferay doesn't support the batch updates because of the cache mechanism that is being used.

HTH..